# Sending request to SOAP web service using Apache http client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-commons-httpclient

I am writing a Java code using `Apache httpclient` to call SOAP web service. So far I have written the below piece of code which is working fine.

```
void post(String strURL, String strSoapAction,  String strXMLFilename) throws Exception{
        
        File input = new File(strXMLFilename);
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);
        RequestEntity entity = new FileRequestEntity(input, "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        post.setRequestEntity(entity);
        post.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", strSoapAction);
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        try {
            int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
            System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
            System.out.println("Response body: ");
            System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Here, **strXMLFilename** is SOAP request file taken from SOAP UI (I copied SOAP UI request XML and paste it in some new XML file and then used it).
The above tests a service that takes String as an argument.

But now my question is will it be able to test a service that is taking File as an input? I need to send a File to the service. In SOAP UI, I am able to attach a file and test the service but not able to do the same with the above piece of code.

Answer (score -2):

Ok buddy try this one it worked fine for me

```
  void sendRequest()throws Exception {  
    System.out.println("Start sending " + action + " request");  
    URL url = new URL( serviceURL );  
    HttpURLConnection rc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  
    //System.out.println("Connection opened " + rc );  
    rc.setRequestMethod("POST");  
    rc.setDoOutput( true );  
    rc.setDoInput( true );   
    rc.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" );  
    String reqStr = reqT.getRequest();  
    int len = reqStr.length();  
    rc.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( len ) );  
    rc.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapActions[actionLookup(action)] );  
    rc.connect();      
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter( rc.getOutputStream() );   
    out.write( reqStr, 0, len );  
    out.flush();  
    System.out.println("Request sent, reading response ");  
    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader( rc.getInputStream() );  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     
    int ch = read.read();  
    while( ch != -1 ){  
      sb.append((char)ch);  
      ch = read.read();  
    }  
    response = sb.toString();  
    read.close();  
    rc.disconnect();  
  }
```

Comment: what is 'reqT' object on which getRequest is invoked??

Comment: HttpClient is not used in your case. The question is to make use of HttpClient.